# Can I supply negative values to IntConstraintOccurrence?

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I want to enable both positive and negative soft constraints in my application. A +2 implies a positive constraint of weight 2 and a -1 implies a negative constraint of weight 1. Can I supply a negative value as a `NEGATIVE_SOFT` to imply that it is a **positive** soft contraint?

```
insertLogical(new IntConstraintOccurrence("sameDayOrderDifferentDays", 
ConstraintType.NEGATIVE_SOFT,-8,
    $stp1,$stp2));
```

---

Otherwise how can I set enable positive and negative soft constraints without having separate rules that inserts `NEGATIVE_SOFT` and `POSITIVE_SOFT` depending on the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can

there is also ConstraintType.POSITIVE_SOFT which are meant for positive constraints., but
using 2 accumulates in the same rule is a bad idea, so I d advise to only one type and indeed work with negative numbers too.

Please create a jira issue that this needs to be documented better.

Comment: In the end, only what is put into the scoreCalculator matters. IntConstraintOccurrence is just a helper class.

Comment: I should probably merge NEG and POS_SOFT, but easier multi level support will do that.